# Accesing child value in JSON

Tags: c#, json, parsing

How can i acces the first item id?

```
    using (var http = new HttpClient())
    {
        var res = JArray.Parse(await http.GetStringAsync("http://api.champion.gg/champion/Gragas?api_key=????").ConfigureAwait(false));
                  ^^^^^^ // Also tried with JObject instead of JArray, both don't work
        var champion = (Uri.EscapeUriString(res[0]["items"][0]["mostGames"][0]["items"][0]["id"].ToString()));
        Console.WriteLine(champion);        //  ^ [0] here because the JSON starts with an [
    }
```

Example JSON result (made it smaller because the original JSON is over 21500 characters, made sure its valid with https://jsonlint.com, here is the original JSON response: https://hastebin.com/sacikozano.json)

```
[{
    "key": "Gragas",
    "role": "Jungle",
    "overallPosition": {
        "change": 1,
        "position": 13
    },
    "items": {
        "mostGames": {
            "items": [{
                    "id": 1402,
                    "name": "Enchantment: Runic Echoes"
                },
                {
                    "id": 3158,
                    "name": "Ionian Boots of Lucidity"
                },
                {
                    "id": 3025,
                    "name": "Iceborn Gauntlet"
                },
                {
                    "id": 3065,
                    "name": "Spirit Visage"
                },
                {
                    "id": 3742,
                    "name": "Dead Man's Plate"
                },
                {
                    "id": 3026,
                    "name": "Guardian Angel"
                }
            ],
            "winPercent": 50.45,
            "games": 300
        }
    }
}]
```

With JArray i get the following error: `Accessed JObject values with invalid key value: 0. Object property name expected.`

With JObject i get the following error: `Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path '', line 1, position 1.`

Thanks in advance, i hope i explained it well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
var champion = (Uri.EscapeUriString(res[0]["items"]["mostGames"]["items"][0]["id"].ToString()));
```

The outermost `"items"` property has a single object as its value, not an array, so `[0]` is not needed in `["items"][0]`.  Similarly `"mostGames"` has a single object value so the `[0]` is not needed in `["mostGames"][0]`.

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wD7zH4).

Note that if `"items"` is *sometimes* an array of objects, but *sometimes* is a single object instead of an array of one object, you can introduce the following extension method:

```
public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<JToken> AsArray(this JToken item)
    {
        if (item is JArray)
            return (JArray)item;
        return new[] { item };
    }
}
```

And do:

```
var champion = (Uri.EscapeUriString(res[0]["items"].AsArray().First()["mostGames"]["items"][0]["id"].ToString()));
```

Comment: U are a true god